# Assign new column using a set of sub-columns

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with a column 'name' of the form ['A','B','C',A','B','B'....] and a set of arrays: one corresponding to 'A', say array_A = [0, 1, 2 ...] and array_B = [3, 1, 0 ...], array_C etc...
I want to create a new column 'value' by assigning array_A where the row name in the dataframe is 'A', and similarly for 'B' and 'C'.

The function `df['value']=np.where(df['name']=='A',array_A, df['value'])` won't do it because it would overwrite the values for other names or have dimensionality issues.

For example:

```
arrays = {'A': np.array([0, 1, 2]),
          'B': np.array([3, 1])}
```

Desired output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B']})

  name  value 
0    A      0 
1    B      3  
2    A      1  
3    A      2  
4    B      1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop with a dictionary:

```
arrays = {'A': np.array([0, 1, 2]),
          'B': np.array([3, 1])}

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B']})

for k, v in arrays.items():
    df.loc[df['name'] == k, 'value'] = v

df['value'] = df['value'].astype(int)

print(df)

  name  value
0    A      0
1    B      3
2    A      1
3    A      2
4    B      1
```